# Receiving "potentially dangerous Request.Form" with requestValidationMode = 2.0

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass raw HTML using ViewBag and Html.Raw, I have another instance of logic identical to this that works in my app but when I duplicated it on another page I'm getting this error again.

I have already enabled `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` in my config file. Why am I still getting this message? Shouldn't this allow it across the entire application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `[ValidateInput(false)]`  in your method.